# multiple points with UIBezierPath in UIView , what formula to apply?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, formula, uibezierpath

I'm working on an app on IOS with Xcode (objective-c)

Here is the problem :

I'm working on a new way to show some statistics based on some frequency in a day, every hours.

Here is what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

What you see is sort of clock on a 24 hour basis (top = 0 o'clock, each 15 degrees is an hour)
Each hour i have a distance from the center of the circle.

Those values are known, what I have hard time to achieve, is the curves themselves !

Indeed, In an UIView, I think i need to use UIBezierPath to draw the curves, but i have no clue on what formula I need to apply in order to make the graph passing through all the points ?

I hope I am clear with this question. Don't hesitate to ask me to clarify myself !

Thanks again, and see ya later !